# \textsc and acronym

Tags: acronyms

I am willing to use the [`acronym`](http://ctan.org/pkg/acronym) package in a paper and I'd like to show the acronym in `\textsc`.

Unfortunately the documentation of the package says that my acronym can be only an ASCII character.
http://staff.science.uva.nl/~polko/HOWTO/LATEX/acronym.html

Is there a way to do what I'd like to do?

Comment: The *label* associated with the acronym can only be ASCII. The acronym itself can be anything supported by LaTeX. Your link mentions: "You can define acronyms with `\acrodef{label}[acronym]{written out form}`, for example  `\acrodef{etacar}[$\eta$ Car]{Eta Carinae}`, with the restriction that the `label` should be simple ASCII." Note the use of math mode `$..$` in the `acronym`. Do you want `\textsc` as the default for all your acronyms or just some?

Comment: For me it is ok to set something like \acrodef{API}[\textsc{API}]{Application Programming Interface} but it is not working as expected and what I get is the usual plain text.

Comment: Nevermind, I tried it again and it worked. It just required an additional compilation.

Comment: I've converted my comment into an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *label* associated with the acronym can only be ASCII. The acronym itself can be anything supported by LaTeX. Your link mentions:

> You can define acronyms with `\acrodef{label}[acronym]{written out
>   form}`, for example `\acrodef{etacar}[$\eta$ Car]{Eta Carinae}`, with
>   the restriction that the `label` should be simple ASCII.

Note the use of math mode `$..$` in the acronym. As such, using `\acrodef{..}[\textsc{...}]{...}` will achieve the desired output.